# Keyword property revision

Tags: svn, properties, tortoisesvn

I am working with tortoisesvn and encountered the Keyword Property for Revision, which I now use to mark my files with a Version. I encountered the problem that I want one file to have always the latest Revision Number showed. Is there a way to change the revision key word to be updated on every commit not just if the file changed?

Comment: You would have to commit the file every single time someone makes a commit in order to do that. It doesn't seem like the best idea to do that anyway, considering let's say the version this file (let's call it `A`) was added to the repository at revision `1`.. Why would five separate commits to `B``C``D``E` and `F` update `A`  to revision `6` if no changes were made to it? Would it be easier to simply make some sort of config file that gets updated whenever you release another version of this particular application/file?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that using TortoiseSVN and the keyword svn property.

However, as Chris wrote in comments, I don't see how it could be useful to do that.
It may be an XY problem: maybe you should try to explain the original goal of your request.